# Integral by method of residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I want to integrate $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$ along the curve $\gamma(t)=2+\frac{1}{2}e^{it}$, with $t\in [0,2\pi]$

Can this be done by mean of residues? The curve is not closed, so I think it might be a problem.  The fact that exercise was in a chapter calleed "Cauchy integral formula and residues" suggest that this theorems should be used to solve the integral

Comment: But isn’t the curve closed? $e^{it}$ describes a complete circle from $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: The curve is a circle with radius 1/2 centered about (0, 2). Only one of your poles are in the circle.

Comment: @Kaynex But when $t=0$ doesn't it give the point $(2,0)$?

Comment: Derp, flipped my coordinates. But you know what I mean, and the important part is the pole in the circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curve *is* closed. What made you think it is not?

You can compute is using Cauchy's integral formula:\begin{align}\int_\gamma\frac z{(z-1)(z-2)}\,\mathrm dz&=\int_\gamma\frac{\frac z{z-1}}{z-2}\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi i\frac2{2-1}\\&=4\pi i.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The curve $\gamma$ described parametrically by $z=2+\frac12e^{it}$, $t\in [0,2\pi]$ is a circle centered at $z=2$ with radius $1/2$.  That curve encloses the pole of $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ at $z=2$, but not at $z=1$.

From the residue theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz&=\int_{|z-2|=\frac12} \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i\text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}, z=2\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \lim_{z\to 2}(z-2)\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}\\\\
&=4\pi i
\end{align}$$